# a query that returns a single row for each foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a table of routines. In this table, I have the column "grade" (which is not mandatory), and the column "date". Also, I have a number of days and an array of ids of users. I need a query that returns me the last routine that have a value != null for "grade" column and datediff(current_date,date) >= number_of_days for each id in the array and make an average of all these values.

e.g.

```
today = 2014/10/15

number_of_days = 10

ids(1,3)
```

routines

```
id  | type | date       | grade | user_id
1   | 1    | 2014-10-10 | 3     | 1
2   | 1    | 2014-10-04 | 3     | 1
3   | 1    | 2014-10-01 | 3     | 1
4   | 1    | 2014-09-24 | 2     | 1
5   | 1    | 2014-10-10 | 2     | 2
6   | 1    | 2014-10-04 | 3     | 2
7   | 1    | 2014-10-01 | 3     | 2
8   | 1    | 2014-09-24 | 1     | 2
9   | 1    | 2014-10-10 | 1     | 3
10  | 1    | 2014-10-04 | 1     | 3
11  | 1    | 2014-10-01 | 1     | 3
12  | 1    | 2014-09-24 | 1     | 3
```

In this case, my query would return an avg between "grade" of row id #2 and #10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're saying that you want to consider rows having non-null values in the grade column, a date within a given number of days of the current date, and one of a given set of user_ids.  Among those rows, for each user_id you want to choose the row with the latest date, and compute an average of the grade columns for those rows.

I will assume that you cannot have any two rows with the same user_id and date, both with non-null grades, else the question you want to ask does not have a well-defined answer.

A query along these lines should do the trick:

```
SELECT AVG(r.grade) AS average_grade
  FROM 
    (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS date
      FROM routines
      WHERE grade IS NOT NULL
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) >= 10
        AND user_id IN (1,3)
      GROUP BY user_id) AS md
    JOIN routines r
      ON r.user_id = md.user_id AND r.date = md.date
```

Note that in principle you need a `grade IS NOT NULL` condition on both the inner and the outer query to select the correct rows to average, but in practice `AVG()` ignores nulls, so you don't actually have to filter out the extra rows in the outer query.